# How long does it take a PS4 controller to charge enough to turn on?

Tags: ps4

If the PS4 controller is completely drained, how long does it take for it to fully recharge?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "turn it back on" the 'it' is the PS4 *with* the controller as the activating device.

The wait time is dependent upon whether you have plugged it in to charge before attempting to power it on.

If you attempt to turn the PS4 on without charging the dead controller, the wait before you can turn it on with to controller is indefinite.

If you attempt to turn the PS4 on while the controller is connected with a USB and charging, the power can be turned on immediately.

However, it may be a good idea to leave the PS4 controller plugged in to charge before disconnecting so that the controller doesn't power off almost immediately.

According to the [Sony website](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/basic/usecontroller.html) a full controller charge from complete discharge takes about 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It takes about 1-3 hours of charging for it to work.